# Linux command-line program that switches consoles?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, console

For whatever reason, the `Ctrl-Alt-Fn` sequence has no effect on one of my Ubuntu machines; the sequence is interpreted as ordinary input.  I need to get the system to a console.

Is there a command-line tool that can be used to switch consoles?

(I'm running Ubunty Jaunty at the moment. Yes I know it's old; I'm trying to march forward.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/33065/console-commands-to-change-virtual-ttys-in-linux-and-openbsd) which suggests using the command **chvt** should help (assuming I've understood your requirement correctly)

Comment: Opps - saw you've just posted the same thing!  At least I didn't get it wrong then! :-)

Comment: That works fine but only if you are logged into a shell. In console but without shell (i.e.not logged in), you cannot issue `chvt your-target-tty-nbr`. That's a problem sometimes. To cycle through yr consoles the simplest thing is to use `ALT+left (or right) arrow`. This OP is old. I only had this for reference. – Cbhihe 9 mins ago

Answer (score 4):

Found it: `chvt` is exactly what I was looking for. The [console how-to](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.html) has good stuff in it.